# how to enclose selection in {} using vim-latex keyboard shortcuts

Tags: vim, keyboard

Is there an easy way of wrapping a selected text in {}  with a shortcut in the same way you can turn a text into italics by typing `` `it `` while selecting a piece of text.

I tried `` `{ `` but and that works but formatting the {}'s as for text not commands

e.g to transform "Computational Skills Learned:"

what happens is:

`\left\{ Computational Skills Learned: \right\}`

This is not what I want, I want

`{Computational Skills Learned:}`

Comment: Use *only* `\{` and `\}`, not `\left\{` and `\right\}`. Are you referring to defining a shortcut in `vim-latex` that would embrace your selection with `{` and `}`?

Comment: I am not typing that. That happens when I type  `'{`

Yes, I want to know if there is already a shortcut that does that. As `'it` does for turning a text into italics

Comment: not vim-latex, but I use [surround.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) plugin so I can, for example, visual-select word(s) and `s}` to enclose it in curvy brackets.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As morbusg mentioned, the [surround plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround) is the way to go.

You select the text eg. using visual mode, then you press `S` and the *closing* brace `}`. You can use any character with a matching partner: `]`, `>`, `)`, etc. If you use the *left* part of the pair, it additionally surrounds the selected text with a space. Example:

```
Computational Skills Learned:
```

Assuming the cursor is on the “C” in “Computational”, then you press `vf:S}` and you get this result:

```
{Computational Skills Learned:}
```

If you press `vf:S[` the result is:

```
[ Computational Skills Learned: ]
```

**Note:** In older versions the small `s` was used, but it has been changed in favour of the capital `S`.

Comment: In case anyone wonders, in normal vim `s` is a synonym for `cl` and `S` for `cc`. Neither of the seem particular important to me. You can always use `map s S` to have surround on lower case `s`.